What is the difference between a 225j 400V capacitor and a 105j 400V capacitor?
I am trying to build an AC to 12V 1A DC power supply.

'400 V' capacitors are not suitable for connecting to mains.

The difference is 1.2uF.
Ok, but seriously now…
A capacitor value marking of 105 is 1 uF, 225 is 2.2 uF. It’s the first two digits followed by the third digit number of zeros in picofarads, so 225 is 2200000 pF which is 2.2 uF.
The j means 5% tolerance.
If you are trying as I suspect to build a capacitive voltage dropper to get a 12 V supply from AC line voltage without a transformer for galvanic isolation I would recommend against it, those can be lethal if you don’t know what you’re doing (and even if you do) and your question suggests that you are a beginner in electronics.
